# Snort Version 3.1.78.0. I am unable to locate the snort.conf file on my Linux system

Tags: snort

I have checked the `/etc/snort/` and `/usr/local/etc/snort/` directories but could not find the `snort.conf` file. I also attempted to use the

```
sudo find / -name snort.conf
sudo find / -type f -name snort.conf
```

and

```
locate snort.conf
```

commands to search for the file throughout the filesystem but did not find it.

Should I create a new `snort.conf` file, or should I continue searching for an existing configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `snort` [documentation](https://www.snort.org/documents#OfficialDocumentation) the config file is named `snort.lua` and it is located in `/etc/snort`. Maybe you should concentrate on [snort rules](https://www.snort.org/downloads#rules) which actually define the way snort will detect malicious activities.

Comment: Dear Romeo Ninov, thank you for the information! I've found it by your help.

Comment: If you are happy with particular answer you can accept it (tick on the left from answer)